# using url scheme how to redirect to a specific visual force screen of salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I have got the task to redirect to salesforce1 iOS app product catalog screen(which is a vf page)from my iOS app using url scheme.Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried with below things but instead of opening a page its only opening an individual record or its just redirecting to salesforce1 app.

This is the link which i want to change to custom url scheme to open a visual force page in salesforce1 app.

```
https://c.cs7.visual.force.com/apex/vfpagename?sfdc.tabName=01rC0000000M4gR
```

I have tried:

```
salesforce1://sObject/id/view

salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=apex/vfpagename?id=01rC0000000M4gR
```

Comment: The id you are passing in: `01rC0000000M4gR` is not a record, rather it is the metadata id value for the tab.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your response. But I am trying to open a custom  visual force screen not a particular record. So lets say i just want to open the my vfpage screen like when i click a tab from menu of salesforce1 app. I found few people are saying to try like this: salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=apex/vfpagename but still its not taking me the particular screen instead its just navigating to the app.

Comment: My point is simply that this: `id=01rC0000000M4gR` is typically reserved for a record ID. So that is where you'd put the account ID (or whatever other record it was supposed to be).

Comment: Now that I looked at that, I notice that you are passing `?` into the URL params twice. Should that be more like: `salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=apex/vfpagename&id=01rC0000000M4gR`. Note the `&` before the `id` param.